# List of all guild's custom emojis

Tags: discord, discord.py

Is there any way to get a list of all custom emojis in a guild? For example:

```py
@bot.command()
asyncs def emojis(ctx):
    await(ctx.send.guild.emojis)
```

*This is just an example. I would like a list of emojis for future code writing.*

I tried writing more, so I tried something like this:

```py
for i in ctx.send.guild.emojis:
    await ctx.send(i)
```

But I was unsuccessful anyway, so I'm starting to think that there is no normal way to get a list of custom emojis (by normal I mean fastest way to get a list of custom emojis (not like making a [emoji1,emoji2] by yourself))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `Guild.emojis` is already a tuple, if you really want it as a list you can convert it with the `list` function

```py
custom_emojis = list(ctx.guild.emojis)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.emojis`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.emojis)